# Are questions about atmospheric radiation on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

One aspect that there are few questions (so far) about atmospheric radiation (e.g. ultraviolet  A and B; applications of Beer's Law; etc).  I am a bit biased about this as it is my primary area of expertise - I have seen these on Physics.SE, but with very little attention over there.

Would questions related to atmospheric radiation be on topic?

An example question would be the interaction with particular aerosols with solar UV radiation.  If so, I can happily write a few QA's for them.

Edited to add: related, would it be feasible to create a [atmospheric-radiation](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atmospheric-radiation) tag once I get started.

Comment: We will be happy to take physics.se rejects :)

Answer (score 7):

IMHO, yes. Some questions might get better answers over on Physics.SE, but so long as they are relevant to the situation on Earth I think they're on topic.